# How to create a single array to represent a 3D grid of points in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So what I'm trying to do is create a 3D grid in python that can be used to interpolate some data I will be given at each of the points on the grid. What I want is to be able to have one 3D array that I can use to pick any point on the grid. For example if  I wanted to pick the point along the 3rd row of x, the 2nd row of y and the 1st row of z I would do `points[0, 1, 2]`.

I've started with this:

```
X, Y, Z = np.arange(-0.75, 0.751, 0.5), np.arange(-0.75, 0.751, 0.5), np.arange(-0.75, 0.751, 0.5)
```

Giving me what possible values of x,y and z a point can have. The grid I will be required to make will have equally spaced points. I would preferably like to keep everything in numpy.

Comment: you're close: `XX,YY,ZZ = np.meshgrid(X,Y,Z)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) along with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
r = np.arange(-0.75, 0.751, 0.5)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(r, r, r)
```

This will be fine for a small number of elements, but generally you may prefer to use [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to minimize total roundoff error across the span:

```
r = np.linspace(-0.75, 0.75, 4)
```

You can achieve a similar result by coding the grid "manually" with [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
scale = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
offset = [-0.75, -0.75, -0.75]
np.indices((4, 4, 4), dtype=float) * scale + offset
```

The order of the arrays will be different than with `meshgrid`. I generally prefer the output of `indices` because of this, and because the arrays are stacked rather than returned as a tuple.